# return value of mongodb aggregation with $out as the last stage in aggregation pipeline

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I want to execute a MongoDB aggregation pipeline with Spring Data MongoDB. The last step in that pipeline is writing out all documents to the collection `targetCollection` in the same database.

I implemented the pipeline with an `@Aggregation` annotation in my MongoRepository:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends MongoRepository<Person, String> {
    
    @Meta(allowDiskUse = true)
    @Aggregation(pipeline = {"{$group: { .... } }", "{$out: 'targetCollection'}" })
    Stream<Person> deduplicateToTargetCollection();
}
```

As the Collection has a significant number of Documents I don't want the Documents of the new Collection I am writing to with this aggregation pipeline to be transferred from MongoDB to the Java application.

However, putting a void return type on the method signature of `deduplicateToTargetCollection()` does not work. So, the best I could come up with was setting the return type to `Stream`.

Is the assumption correct that if I just close that `Stream` and don't query it for its elements there isn't any transfer of the Documents in the newly created Collection to the Spring Data MongoDB Java application that executes the aggregation? Does anyone know whether this is documented anywhere to confirm?

Much appreciate any help here.

Comment: With the `$out` as the last stage of an aggregation, the resulting cursor will be empty. So, the method can return `List<Person>` (which will have a size  zero).

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, that is not what happens. Instead, the resultant List<Person> contains all Person entities that were written in the $out pipeline stage.

Comment: There's not yet a way to skip the output, please watch [spring-data-mongodb#4088](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/issues/4088) for updates.